# SQLite certain word colors

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Im busy with a Bible app and want to have text references in a different color than the rest of the text. Is there a way to do this? I use a SQLite db thats in my Assets folder so I edit the data in DB Browser and not in Android Studio as strings.

I want to know if something is possible like `<textcolor>word<textcolor>` and then when its in Android studio it should not display the words in brackets but actually that color. Ive got this example from someone that uses it in php but it doesnt work in SQLite

`<sup><font color="#3923D6">words in color goes here</font></sup>`

Is there a workaround to make this work in Adroid Studio?

Comment: `and then when its in Android studio it should not display the words in brackets but actually that color` You wanted the IDE to change its text color? or you mean that change certain text color in your app?

Comment: You can achieve this by two ways, first if you know the exact text from data then you can use spannable string and format your text as per requirement and another way is store your data in database with html format and then after getting data use Html.fromHtml when you set data as text to lable

Comment: why you want colors in sqlite

Comment: @siddhesh Im busy with a Bible app and want to have text references in a different color than the rest of the text.

Comment: @Vickyexpert could you please explain and give an example of your first way, I know which text I want to change so I would think its the easiest way...

Comment: @Enzokie in the app... While the user reads the words I specified should be in a different color

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm assuming that you want to display the name of the color in it's respective color, like if the text is RED and you want RED to be displayed in red color.

For this you can store the values in your database something like this

```
 "<font color='red'>RED</font>."
```

You can make that column in the table as `TEXT NOT NULL`

Once you fetch this data from table you can display it in TextView as follow

```
 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(colorText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Here `colorText` is the String value you retrieved from database.

Comment: Nope... Im busy with a Bible app and want to have text references in a different color than the rest of the text...

Answer (score 0):

Please check below both options for setting color in text,

**Option1:** Using **"Spannable"**

**Note:** For this you need to import below two packages.

```
 import android.text.Spannable;
 import android.text.SpannableString;
```

Now, let’s say you have some string in mainString as below and you want to make some part of text with different color, so first you need to convert your text in spannable then you can set span as per your requirement.

Below I will try to make text color blue for "making text”, so below is the code for that, you can use it as per your requirement

```
  String mainString = "This is example of making text color using span in android";

  Spannable spanText = new SpannableString(mainString);
  spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), mainString.indexOf("making text"), 11, 0); // This will make making text with blue color


  spanText.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 5, 14 , 0);   // This will make your text bold from 5th to 10 characters.

  yourTextView.setText(spanText);
```

**Option 2:** Using **Database**

For second option you need to store your data using Html in database let’s say you are storing same above line in database so you need to store it as

```
       // This is your main String
       //String mainString = "This is example of making text color using span in android";

        // Store it as below in database
        String mainString = "This is <b> example of</b> <font color='blue'> making text </font> color using span in android";
```

Now when you will get this data at that time just set it as below

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mainString));
```

That's it, you can do by any one of following way.

Comment: Looks good except my data is in sqlite, is there a way to define my hole database as a string?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that {\cf15 this will be grey} will turn the words "this will be grey" in the brackets grey. I a have tried 01 - 20 after the "cf" to achieve different colors.

also, {\i this will be italic} works for italics and they can be combined without using spaces such as: {\cf15\i this will be grey and italic.
Hope this helps.